# Remove array keys from without removing the key values

Tags: php, arrays

Can any one please tell me how to remove the array key from array without removing the key value. For example:

This is my value:

```
$arr = array("1"=>2,"2"=>5,"3"=>10);
```

What I want is:

```
$arr = array(2,5,10);
```

If both equal how the default keys are assigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) function:

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/array_values):

> `array_values()` returns all the values from the input array and indexes the array numerically.

Answer (score 0):

please use this function

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_value() for your purpose.

```
$arr           = array("1"=>2,"2"=>5,"3"=>10);
$array_values  = array_values($arr);
```